# Simple if-statement seems to be not executing some portion of code

Tags: java, android, if-statement

When I press a button, the code below is called. If `currentImageButton` is null, and it's `Drawable` is null (which it will be the first time it is called), then simply print a message to the console. Otherwise, set the background of my canvas to an image in my Drawable folder. I know the condition is sometimes true, because `"currentImageButton DOES have a drawing cache"` is printed out after the first button press.

```
            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view;

            if (currentImageButton != null && currentImageButton.getDrawable() != null) {

                Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start_checklist_pressed);
                Bitmap anImage      = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
                canvas.drawBitmap(anImage);

                System.out.println("currentImageButton DOES have a drawing cache");
            } else {
                System.out.println("currentImageButton has no drawing cache");

            }

            currentImageButton = imageButton;
```

However, when the condition is true, the background of my canvas is never set. The weird thing is, I know those lines of code work, because when I bring the last line underneath the first, everything works perfectly, although that line seems completely irrelevant to whether or not the background gets set. This code works:

```
            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view;
            currentImageButton = imageButton;

            if (currentImageButton != null && currentImageButton.getDrawable() != null) {

                Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start_checklist_pressed);
                Bitmap anImage      = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
                canvas.drawBitmap(anImage);

                System.out.println("currentImageButton DOES have a drawing cache");
            } else {
                System.out.println("currentImageButton has no drawing cache");

            }
```

What is going on here?

**EDIT**

Also, another weird thing. If I change the condition to OR:

```
if (currentImageButton != null || currentImageButton.getDrawable() != null)
```

I get a null pointer exception on this line. How is it possible for a null pointer exception to be thrown on a check for null?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.brettrosen.atls.fragments.PrearrivalPlan$6.onClick(PrearrivalPlan.java:416)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4192)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17327)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT2**

currentImageButton is declared as follows, as a global variable:

```
public ImageButton currentImageButton;
```

**EDIT3**

My current implementation. The first time the button is clicked, it doesn't work, as expected. The second time it is clicked, it passed the condition but the background of the canvas is still not set.

```
             Drawable d = imageButton.getDrawable();

            if (d != null) {
                Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start_checklist_pressed);
                Bitmap anImage      = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
                canvas.drawBitmap(anImage);

                System.out.println("worked");
            } else {
                System.out.println("didnt work");
            }
```

Comment: `||` has to evaluate both statements to see if they're ALL true.  So if `currentImageButton` is `null`, it still needs to check if `currentImageButton.getDrawable()` is `null` and... NPE.

Comment: you should share the stacktrace for anyone to tell you why you get the null pointer

Comment: You don't show where `currentImageButton` is declared, but setting the value right before using it vs setting the value *after* you've already used it cannot be expected to do the same thing. In the first version, you using whatever previous value it may have had.

Comment: @Andreas But either way, if the condition for the if-statement is passed, shouldn't the background for my canvas still be set even though it has nothing to do with currentImageButton? In the first code above, the second time the button is clicked, it passes the if statement. However it does not change the background.

Also, I edited my code to show stack trace and where `currentImageButton` is declared

Comment: whats at line number 416 in PrearrivalPlan.java ? A complete stacktrace would be handy to debug here..(you didnot include the Caused by part of the stacktrace here)

Comment: @Radix That was the condition in the if-statement. But even disregarding the NPE, I don't understand how the background could be not getting set, even though the condition evaluates as true.

Comment: Do this : public ImageButton currentImageButton=null;

Comment: I'm just wondering: Do you call `canvas.drawBitmap()` from a `Fragment`?

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau Yes! I really hope this has something to do with it.

Comment: It feels odd to me to get a canvas and call methods on it when I'm not extending `View`. Is there a reason why you don't call `setDrawable()` on the `ImageButton` directly?

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau Well it's not android's canvas its a library called CanvasView. Also, I'm trying to set the drawable of the canvas, not the ImageButton. I updated my problem with what I currently have which still doesn't work.

Comment: Just to make sure this isn't the source of the problem: Did you check that your Bitmap is loaded correctly?

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau Which bitmap? The bitmap that I am trying to draw to my canvas? If so, yes. Because when I take that portion out of the if-statement it works fine. It's only when inside of the if-statement that it doesn't work. Which is weird because it's seemingly completely unrelated to the if-statement check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem i see here is that probably your `currentImageButton` is getting initialized with some garbage reference, hence not equal to null becomes valid, next your `currentImageButton.getDrawable()` gets called which in tern cause NPE in the internal call . In the code that works you have the `currentImageButton= imageButton` , before the if condition

I believe this should solve it

```
public ImageButton currentImageButton=null;
```

Comment: I'm trying to use a better implementation and I changed the if statement to    `Drawable d = imageButton.getDrawable();`
 `if (((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap() != null) {`, but that throws an NPE. I'm not understanding how a check for null is throwing an NPE?

Comment: @Brejuro : It would be really handy to have the full stack trace. Also maybe you should modify your question to give more details for anyone to even replicate your issue.

Comment: @Brejuro If there is no Drawable set on the image button, the call `imageButton.getDrawable()` will return null. Thus, your variable `d` in `d.getBitmap()` is referencing to `null, and you get NPE there.